# scala list.map returns list of empty

Tags: scala, foreach, functional-programming

I'm trying to sum the values of the pairs that have the same character, but when printing,  i get `List((),())`

here's my code

```
var lstA = List(("a",1),("b",2))
var lstB = List(("a",3), ("b",4))

val k = lstA.map(a => lstB.foreach(b => {
  if(b._1 == a._1) (a._1, a._2+b._2) else a
}))

println(k)
```

of course there are better ways to do this, but I just want to know why this isn't working.
when debugging and evaluating the line   `if(b._1 == a._1) (a._1, a._2+b._2) else a` i get the values of pairs as expected however when printing the list `k` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and not entirely accurate answer is because `foreach` doesn't return anything. Actually, though, it *does* return something. Here is the [signature](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@foreach(f:A=%3EUnit):Unit):

```
def foreach[U](f: (A) ⇒ U): Unit
```

It returns a `Unit` type, which is used as a signal that the function has side-effects. From the documentation, the `f` parameter is:

> the function that is applied for its side-effect to every element. The
>   result of function f is discarded.

So the function is expected to have a side effect. This could be something like `println`.